# DrRacket - Display all the values in a list that are above average

Tags: racket

I'm creating a function that consumes a list of numbers and produces the elements in the list that are above average.
Below is my code:

```
(define (listlength list)
        (cond
            ((empty? list) 0)
            (else (+ 1 (listlength (rest list))))))

(define (listsum list)
  (cond
    [(empty? list) 0]
    [else (+ (first list)
             (listsum (rest list)))]))

(define (average log)
  (/ (listsum log) (+ (listlength log) 1)))

(define (average-filter log)
  (cons
  (cond
    [(> (first log) (average log)) (first log)]
    [else (average-filter (rest log))])))
```

So obviously there is something wrong with my code...Can someone help me?
The error message for (average-filter (cons 40 (cons 30 empty) is:

> cons: expects 2 arguments, but found only 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of comments: in the `average` procedure, there's no need to add 1 to the denominator, but you should handle the case when it's zero. Also notice that you can improve your solution by calculating the `average` only once, it'll be the same for the input list, so you don't need to recalculate it at every iteration. And please don't call your parameters `list` or `log`, they will clash with existing procedures.

Now for the real issue with `average-filter`: it's the same error of your previous question, you must *not* put the `cons` part at the beginning, that's not how it works. You should call `cons` with the current element *and the result of the recursive call*, to build a list with the results. And you *must* have a base case, think about it: what would happen when you run out of elements to traverse? that's the point where you need to return an empty list:

```
(define (average-filter lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [(> (first lst) (average lst))
     (cons (first lst) (average-filter (rest lst)))]
    [else (average-filter (rest lst))]))
```

Please, spend some time studying the proper way to build an output list as a result of traversing an input list, notice that you need to:

1. Handle the case when the input list is empty.
2. `cons` the current element with the result of the recursive call, when it makes sense to do it.

Comment: First, thank you for your help! And here's another question: Since (average lst) is in (average-filter lst) it always computes the average of the rest of the list, instead of the average of the original list..So how do I calculate average lst only once?

Comment: @Sillage by writing another function that passes the average to `average-filter` as a parameter (you need to add an extra parameter). Anyway it's not mandatory, your answer works, it's just not the fastest way to do it, but for small lists (less than a thousand elements) you won't even notice it.

Comment: Sorry if I sound stupid but how do I define a new parameter as average lst since lst is not defined at this moment?

Comment: Don't worry too much about it, your answer is fine. If you insist on it,  just declare the procedure like this: `(define (average-filter lst) (average-filter-helper lst (average lst)))`. And `(define (average-filter-helper lst avg) ...` is your implementation, only that you don't compute the `average` every time, just use the parameter you received when you called it from `average-filter`. Again, if this seems like too much trouble, leave it as you currently have it.